# How to initialize an array of 2D-arrays?

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array, initialization, array-initialization

I have an array of 2D-arrays. For example, it is like:

```
{{{0, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 0}}
{{0, 0, 3}, {2, 1, 2}, {2, 2, 1}, {3, 0, 0}}
{{0, 0, 7}, {3, 2, 6}, {6, 2, 3}, {6, 3, 2}, {7, 0, 0}}}
```

But If I write

```
int [,][] arrays={{{0, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 0}}
                  {{0, 0, 3}, {2, 1, 2}, {2, 2, 1}, {3, 0, 0}}
                  {{0, 0, 7}, {3, 2, 6}, {6, 2, 3}, {6, 3, 2}, {7, 0, 0}}};
```

the compiler will complain "; expected".

If I write

```
int [,][] arrays={new int[,] {{0, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 0}}
                  new int[,] {{0, 0, 3}, {2, 1, 2}, {2, 2, 1}, {3, 0, 0}}
                  new int[,] {{0, 0, 7}, {3, 2, 6}, {6, 2, 3}, {6, 3, 2}, {7, 0, 0}}};
```

the compiler will complain

> "A nested array initializer is expected".

So why does this happen and what is the correct way of initialization?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You're trying to create jagged array. Your array has `n` rows so your first square should be [] not [,]. Element in each row (index of `n`) is 2D array so you need to use `[,]`. Finally, you can fix your problem by change int `[,][]` to `int[][,]`.

```
int[][,] arrays = {
    new int[,] {{0, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 0}},
    new int[,] {{0, 0, 3}, {2, 1, 2}, {2, 2, 1}, {3, 0, 0}},
    new int[,] {{0, 0, 7}, {3, 2, 6}, {6, 2, 3}, {6, 3, 2}, {7, 0, 0}}
};
```

Comment: I add `new int[,][]` at the beginning but the error is still there.

Comment: Ahh, I see your problem, I have add correction code from your example.

Comment: It works~ I thought `int[,]` is a type so the array of this type would be `int[,][]`. Why is it so?

Comment: Add more explanation, hope this help. :)

Answer (score 3):

An array of 2d arrays is a 3d array:

```
int[, ,] array3D = new int[,,] { { { 1, 2, 3 } }, { { 4, 5, 6 } } };
```

Also see more at MSDN
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2yd9wwz4(v=VS.90).aspx

Comment: But that makes fixed outermost index, which is clear from his question he wants not fixed

Comment: A 3d array also requires that all 3 indices be provided, resulting in an integer, whereas the asker wishes to index and get back a 2d array.