# Making a text-based game

Tags: c#, dictionary, arraylist

Me and my friend decided to start making games together in C#. The major issue is that what little we learned in programming 101 in High School have mostly been forgotten, in addition to the fact that we only ever got to program in Javascript.

Deciding to review our old programs we almost immediately ran into issues. We were made to make a game called Wompus, a simple text-based adventure consisting of a single map, a monster and gold. We made the map in Java using this code:

```
static char[][] cave = {

        {'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X'},
        {'X', 'O', 'O', 'X', 'O', 'O', 'X', 'O', 'M', 'X'},
        {'X', 'O', 'X', 'X', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'X'},
        {'X', 'O', 'X', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'X', 'X'},
        {'X', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X'},
        {'X', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'X', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'X', 'X'},
        {'X', 'O', 'O', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'X'},
        {'X', 'O', 'O', 'X', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'X', 'X'},
        {'X', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'X', 'X'},
        {'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X'}};
```

With X representing a wall and O representing an empty space (M and G being Monster and Gold, respectively). However, when transferred into C# we get the error message: "Array initializers can only be used in a variable or field initializer."

This is our first time programming in just over a year and with a new language, so all but the most basic expressions are lost on us. Please help!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I declare a two dimensional string array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3814145/how-can-i-declare-a-two-dimensional-string-array)

Answer (score 1):

*Jugged array* (array of array) is what you're trying to declare. The right syntax is

```
  static Char[][] cave = new Char[][] { // <- new Char[][] - creating an array of array
    // new Char[] <- each line is an array 
    new Char[] {'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X'},
    new Char[] {'X', 'O', 'O', 'X', 'O', 'O', 'X', 'O', 'M', 'X'},
    new Char[] {'X', 'O', 'X', 'X', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'X'},
    new Char[] {'X', 'O', 'X', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'X', 'X'},
    new Char[] {'X', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X'},
    new Char[] {'X', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'X', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'X', 'X'},
    new Char[] {'X', 'O', 'O', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'X'},
    new Char[] {'X', 'O', 'O', 'X', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'X', 'X'},
    new Char[] {'X', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'X', 'X'},
    new Char[] {'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X'}};
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have to initialize your array with `new` keyword:

```
static char[][] cave = new char[][]{}
```