# Do the number of rows in a C# jagged array have to be pre-counted?

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array

I have been reading about jagged (an array of arrays) in several posts including [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3814145/how-can-i-declare-a-two-dimensional-string-array) one.

I am reading a .csv file into memory. My question is do I have to know the number of rows in the .csv file in advance, or can I just assign a new row to the array?

I think this is not possible, based on looking at people's examples.

My current code (below) works just fine. I am just wondering if there is a way to insert new arrays without first counting the number of rows.

```
public int map_csv()
{
    // cmn 4/26/2016 Don't even bother to try anything with an empty string.

if (0 == m_ret_code)
{
    try
    {
        using (TextFieldParser parser = new TextFieldParser(m_csv_path))
        {
            parser.TextFieldType = FieldType.Delimited;
            parser.SetDelimiters(",");

            m_row_count = 0;

            while (!parser.EndOfData)
            {
                string[] fields = parser.ReadFields();
                m_row_count++;
            }
        }

        m_csv_array = new string[m_row_count][];
        m_row_idx = 0;

        using (TextFieldParser parser = new TextFieldParser(m_csv_path))
        {
            parser.TextFieldType = FieldType.Delimited;
            parser.SetDelimiters(",");

            if (!parser.EndOfData)
            {
                m_column_headings = parser.ReadFields();
                m_csv_array[m_row_idx] = new string[m_column_headings.Length];
                m_csv_array[m_row_idx] = m_column_headings;
                m_row_idx++;
            }

            while (!parser.EndOfData)
            {
                string[] fields = parser.ReadFields();
                m_csv_array[m_row_idx] = new string[fields.Length];
                m_csv_array[m_row_idx] = fields;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        m_exception_msg = e.Message;
        m_ret_code = 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not a `List<string[]>`?

Comment: No reason I cannot do that. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need a `List<string[]>`. You can keep adding `string[]` without having to worry have its size.

---

Or, if you decide to keep your `string[][]`, you can just read the content of the file and split it yourself :

```
m_csv_array = File.ReadAllLines(m_csv_path)
    .Select(x => x.Split(',').ToArray())
    .ToArray()
```

Answer (score 4):

Use a `List<string[]>` instead of an array as the "outer" collection, so you can use its Add method to assign a new string[] to a new row.